# Coroutine does not finish because it has an async associated with it that did not finish, how to run async independently?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was just playing a bit with coroutines, and just noticed a small inconvenience or rather a great feature. But the following code never finishes:

```kotlin
val job = GlobalScope.launch {
    doSomeWork()
    async {
        while(true) { //if removed job.join finishes in 60 seconds
            delay(60000L)
            doRecurringWork()
        }
    }
}

runBlocking {
    job.join()
}
```

It appears that `job` finishes but `job.join` waits for the `async` to finish which is intended to never happen.

Is there any way to unlink an `async` operation from the current coroutine? (running another job solves this issue but avoids the question)

Here's some more detailed code:

```kotlin
val tag="tag"
Log.d(tag,"in main before launch")
val job = GlobalScope.launch {
    Log.d(tag,"in GlobalScope before doSomeWork")
    doSomeWork()
    Log.d(tag,"in GlobalScope after doSomeWork before async")
    async {
        Log.d(tag,"in async before while")
        while(true) { //if removed job.join finishes in 60 seconds
            delay(60000L)
            doRecurringWork()
            Log.d(tag,"in async after doRecurringWork")
        }
        Log.d(tag,"in async after while (die)")
    }
    Log.d(tag,"in GlobalScope after async (die)")
}
Log.d(tag,"in main after launch before runBlocking")
runBlocking {
    Log.d(tag,"in runBlocking before join")
    job.join()
    Log.d(tag,"in runBlocking after join (die)")
}
Log.d(tag,"in main after runBlocking (die)")
    
//log:
//in main before launch
//in main after launch before runBlocking
//in runBlocking before join
//in GlobalScope before doSomeWork
//in GlobalScope after doSomeWork before async
//in async before while
//in GlobalScope after async (die)
//in async after doRecurringWork
//in async after doRecurringWork
//in async after doRecurringWork
```

Note: I switched the code up a bit, people were avoiding the question and focusing on technicalities.

Comment: As far as my knowledge go async spawns a new coroutine that runs independent iff await is not called on the coroutine. Your log suggests that job is finished while your question suggests otherwise.

Comment: Note: log suggests that the `GlobalScope` finished but `job.join` is waiting for the `async`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs are arranged hierarchically.  Your `async` job is a child of your `launch` job, and the parent can't complete until its children complete.

This is close to the whole idea behind "structured concurrency" -- when your job completes you know it's actually done, including all of its asynchronous subtasks.

If you want to do what other languages do, then you can use `GlobalScope.async` instead of just `async`.  Then your parent job can return early, and completely forget about the `async` job, because it's a sibling and not a child.  That job can run forever, silently consuming resources for no good reason.

If you don't want that `async` job to run forever, then you should leave it as a child job, and just cancel it when you don't want to wait for it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for emphasizing the fact that this is a useless edge case, realistically speaking `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)` is for cpu intensive operations, ie: might take 10+ minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`runBlocking` blocks your main thread and then `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` inside the `async` block tries to execute a block of code on already blocked main thread resulting in a deadlock. If you change the dispatcher from `Main` to `IO` then your code will work (But it wont be able to access UI).

Its OK to use `runBlocking` for the purpose of learning and exploration but it should not be used otherwise as it defeats the whole purpose of coroutines.

> Is there any way to unlink an async operation from the current
> coroutine?

There is parent child relationship between a `coroutine` and its children, the parent `Job` becomes complete only when all its children are complete. So there is no way you can say '***consider the parent Job completed while the child async operation is still running***'

see [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/)

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to unlink the `async` coroutine from the `GlobalScope` coroutine, so that `job.join` will just wait until the `GlobalScope` finishes? Ie last line in `GlobalScope` is `Log.d(tag,"in GlobalScope after async")`

Comment: `job.join` is waiting for the` GlobalScope` coroutine to complete, which can only happen when all its children are complete. In your case this is not possible due to the deadlock

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to unlink the `async` coroutine from the `GlobalScope` coroutine so that `job.join` only waits for the first child to complete and not the child of the child?